# Property with quotes unreachable in a Object array with console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js

Assuming I have this Node code in a JS file:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const getStream = require('get-stream').array
const csvParse = require('csv-parser')

async function parse() {
  let geoRows = await getStream(
    fs.createReadStream('./result.csv')
      .pipe(csvParse())
  )
  console.log(geoRows[0])
}
```

It displays (on a console):

```
Row {
  'id': '12345',
  name: 'something' }
```

Something is a bit strange: the `id` is in quote, I don't know why. But my real problem is that this `id` is unreachable:

```
console.log(geoRows[0].id, geoRows[0]['id'], geoRows[0]["'id'"])
```

It displays (on a console):

```
undefined undefined undefined
```

So my (double) question is: **Why? And how can I access to that `id` property?**

*Side note: the only thing that works is `Object.values(geoRows[0])[0]` but it's ugly.*

Comment: Can you verify two things, is getRows[0] returning array or object, also are you getting actual object or JSON. It could that you need parse that to object.

Comment: That output isn't correct json output, so it's hard to understand why your code isn't working

Comment: Can't reproduce here https://jsfiddle.net/6hwvjLa7/ , can you come up with a reproducible example?

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(geoRows[0]))` say?

Comment: What are you getting back with `Object.values(geoRows[0])[0]` ? The id value or an object?

Comment: Are you sure thats the exact same thing that you see in console? Its invalid syntax. You have extra `}`

Comment: Maybe try `geoRows[0]["\'id\'"]`

Comment: What does `Object.keys` give you for that specific row?

Comment: Unable to replicate this issue https://jsfiddle.net/sojitrar88/w2b8oxqj/

Comment: Since that output is not a valid object you won't be able to do anything like `geoRows[0].id`. And as `Object.values(geoRows[0])[0]` works, ugly or not, use it. If you want a better solution we need to see `geoRows` and know what type of object that is, so until then all we can do is guess... And as the given appears to be a string, here is an even uglier solution `geoRows[0].match(/'id': '(\d*)',/)`

Comment: @CallumLinington I edited my question (wrong copypasta)

Comment: @Rajesh Woops. Fixed

Comment: @rap-2-h  if `geoRows[0]` prints object and `geoRows[0].id` prints `undefined`, I suspect there is some hidden character in it. keys are string and are represents normally. If its represented in single quotes, there is some character that we do not see but is present. Try `Object.keys(getRows[0]).find(x => x=== 'id')`